# VB.net Function returning inconsistent results

Tags: vb.net

I created a simple function designed to remove a string of characters from another string and replace it with what ever string the user wants (or no string as a default)

```
Private Function RemoveString(scontainer As String, Optional rcontainer As String = "", Optional rstring As String = "") As String
    Dim container As String = scontainer
    Dim tcontainer As String

    If InStr(container, rcontainer) <> 0 Then
        Do While (InStr(container, rcontainer) <> 0)
            tcontainer = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(container, InStr(container, rcontainer) - 1)
            tcontainer = tcontainer & rstring & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(container, (Len(container) - (InStr(container, rcontainer) + 2)))
            container = tcontainer
        Loop

        RemoveString = container 'return modded string
    Else
        RemoveString = scontainer 'return string as is
    End If
End Function
```

The problem is:
While this is suppose to be a general use function, I really need it to be concerned with 2 different strings

%20
amp;

the function works perfectly for the %20 situation but it leaves the semi-colon behind for the amp; string. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Look at `InStr(container, rcontainer) + 2` - why are you using 2 here?

Comment: As I was typing out my explination I realized why that probably doesn't work. I'm going to try using "+len(rcontainer)"

Comment: You should also look at using `String.Replace`...

Comment: Yay for functions I don't know about :)

Comment: A real mishmash of VB and VB.NET here. :P

Comment: XD I started with VBA and made this entire thing, then my boss told me she didn't want to have to open word to use it. Still learning the differences. It probably doesn't come as a surprise that "VB.NET Developer" is not my job title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I get you right ?
You want to replace a certain char sequence in your string with another char sequence or just delete it.

If thats the case you could use String.Replace(oldValue As String, newValue As String) As String

```
Dim startString as String = "%20 amp;"
Dim resultString as String = startString.Replace("%20 ",String.Empty)
resultString = resultString.Replace(";",String.Empty)
```

After these lines resultString would be "amp"

Comment: No this was not exactly what I was trying to explain but thats my fault. That being said, your answer did provide a peice of information that I was not aware of that did infact contribute to the solution (the string.replace method) and because the first person to bring it up didn't post an answer, I'm marking yours as the answer.